# Trying to create a serial number for every imported image

Tags: lightroom, metadata, image-processing, plugin, capture-one

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the sequence numbers Lightroomor CaptureOne Pro (I'm currently using both) supports in file naming (at import or export) are not continuous, right? In other words, if I import or export 100 images today, and then in a few days import or export another batch, it won't continue at 101 unless I manually tell it to start there. Right?

If so, is there another way to accomplish that, either in the filename or in metadata -- and to do so automatically irrespective of what camera, card, etc was used? Literally a continuously running sequence? A plugin or setting that I've missed?

What I'm effectively trying to achieve is a "serial number" of sorts for all of my photos. Every single photo that gets imported and its variants/clones -- and then preserve its "serial number" any time it's exported so one can easily identify it by referencing the serial number in the filename or by backside prints.﻿

Comment: Does your camera include its serial number and shutter count in the EXIF metadata? If so, does your software workflow preserve that metadata?

Comment: I have 600D, 60D, and (as of next week) 5D Mark IV bodies. I believe all three include serial numbers. Canon does not include shutter counts in EXIF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to add the year, month and date to the filename. With this you can have unique filename. The only problem you will have the filename numbers will not be consecutive.

You can use [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-do-you-manage-images-with-duplicate-file-names-in-lightroom) question/answers as reference/idea

quotes from some of the answers:

> rename the files to include the original shooting date. So instead of
>   IMG_0001.JPG you might end up with 20110214-0001.JPG
>
> instead of IMG_1234.jpg, have the file renamed to
>   IMG_YYYYMMDD_1234.jpg. That way if later down the road you have
>   another IMG_1234.jpg, the exported versions would be dated. So if the
>   images were shot on Feb. 14, 2010 and Jun. 30, 2011 you would end up
>   with IMG_20100214_1234.jpg and IMG_20110630_1234.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create custom templates in COP that will auto-name or auto-rename your files on export. You can set the parameters as you wish.
[image: steps 1 and 2]

[image: step 3]